# Python regex: How to make a group of words/character optional?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make regex that can match all of them:

- word
- word-hyphen
- word-hyphen-again

that is `-\w+`could be many depends on words in a term. How can I make it optional

Thing I made so far is given here:- https://regex101.com/r/Atpwze/1

Comment: use regex `[-\w]+`

Comment: @MaheshKaria can you explain why `-` in the beginning and what `{1,}` doing..

Comment: @MaheshKaria: This is very, very wrong (it would match `"a-a+a+--+"`, for example).

Comment: what is "word" in your terminology?

Comment: In your link, you attempt `\w+(:?-\w+)+`. It is almost right. That last `+` means "1 or more". Make it into `*` ("zero or more), for the correct `\w+(:?-\w+)*`. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/Atpwze/2)'s your updated example at Regex101.

Comment: You can check out https://regexr.com/ to find a lot of helpful info on regex and you can make your own patterns to try to match what you need.

Comment: Use `^\w+(?:-\w+)*$`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

1. `\w+(-\w+)*` for matching 0 or more hyphenated words after first word
2. `\w+(-\w+){0,}` same as first case

based on your exact requirement.

In order to eliminate some extreme cases like `a-+-+---`, you could use `\w+(-\w+)*[^\W]`

- `\W` matches all non-word characters and `^\W` negates the matching of non-word characters

Comment: would be nice to add description with links what each modifier (`*`, `+`, `{n, m}`) does

Comment: This is very, very wrong (it would match `"a-a+a+--+"`, for example). OP never said anything about matching plus signs. Are you mistaking `(?:...)` or `(...)` with `[...]`?

Comment: `+` is equal to `{1,}`

Comment: It still matches `a-------`, which I can't see in the OP's patterns. Are you sure you want to be using square brackets (character class) and not parentheses (group)?

Comment: Oops. i didnt see ur initial comment in full. yeah i was supposed to use `(...)`

Answer (score 0):

To catch all of your examples, I think you could use:

[`^\w+(?:\w+\-?|\-\w+)+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Wcl9NR/1/)

- Beginning of the string `^`
- Match a word character one or more times `\w+`
- Start a non capturing group `(?:`
- Match a word character one or more times with an optional hyphen `\w+\-?`
- Or `|`
- A hyphen with one or more word characters `\-\w+`
- Close the non capturing group `)`
- End of the string `$`